# How to put time delay in COCOS2D Android

Tags: android, design-patterns, cocos2d-iphone, delay

Similar to Android unlock pattern where in, initially all the circular cells will be in grey color. During when we draw some pattern, those cells touched will become green colored and if that pattern is not a correct one, then the cells touched will become red colored and after some 3 seconds, they become grey colored. I am doing similar thing using COCOS2D. I am getting difficulty in introducing that 3 seconds delay before making the cells back to grey colored. Any suggestions...Thanks.

Comment: Did you find solution for your asked question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`CCSequence`** in that first put **`CCDelayTime`** and in second put **`CCCallFuncN`**(which contain logic of again color your circle to grey)

Below i am providing you iOs code logic

```
id action1 = [DelayTime ...];
id action2 = [CallFunc ...];
id seq = [Sequence actions:action1, action2, nil];

[someNode runAction:seq];
```